# How can i get all feeds from my profile using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting only limitted number of feeds i.e**(25 feeds**) from my facebook grapg api and is their any option to get more feeds and  i mentioned **limit=200** in my URL but i am getting only 25.URL is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/posts?access_token={access_token}&limit=200.Is their any way to get this please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

First [get an access token](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), then [retrieve all your feed](https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID/feed?access_token=FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN). Please note that you may need to reiterate the request as the returned content is paginated (that is, `['paging']['next']` element exists inside the answer).

See also [the official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed).

Comment: Mr. Alex can you explain in brief, and how can i do this and while retrieving their is a problem, i am not retrieving all my feeds will you help me, is their any way to retrieve all my **recent feeds**

Comment: i got the solution, go through link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919731/how-to-get-all-posts-of-a-group-via-facebook-graph-api]