# Get all facebook group post using FB Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to get all facebook group post using FB Graph API.
I searched , googled, seen documentation for graph api, asked to so many persons, all are saying it is possible
Also i'm providing link from stackoverflow which i referred and tried
[How to get all posts of a group via facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919731/how-to-get-all-posts-of-a-group-via-facebook-graph-api)
But as you can see the post is very much old (from 2013)

When i tried to send request using CURL, at that time i'm not getting any error not any data

When i tried below code
`$publish = $facebook-api('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/'.$group_id.'/feed/?access_token='.$params['access_token']);`
at least i'm getting something in response

```
Array
(
    [og_object] => Array
        (
            [id] => 859455820800214
            [type] => website
            [updated_time] => 2015-06-04T12:18:15+0000
            [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/659988617465253/feed/
        )
```

```
[share] => Array
    (
        [comment_count] => 0
        [share_count] => 0
    )

[id] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/659988617465253/feed/
```

)
So i just wanted to know that is it really possible at this moment?

And one good thing is that when i'm trying it from Graph API Explorer, i'm getting the data properly.
**So where i'm wrong ?**
**Any little help would be greatly accepted**

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just use the Facebook PHP SDK?

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

You can get the group's feed via `/{group_id}/feed`, as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#read

Make sure your Access Token is of the right type and contains the right permissions.

Comment: thanks Tobi, but can i know what to pass in **$session** variable **(from the 2nd link which you provided, i'm trying to use php sdk )** as it is not mentioned anywhere in documentation

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Use the PHP SDK, if you instanciate it right there should be no need to fill any $session stuff manually. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/4.0.0

Comment: Thanks so much Tobi , it worked , but now i want to show this group posts on my external website But i want to get them without login whenever everytime my website loads How i can do that?

Comment: That's another question. Please don't change the scope of the current question.

Comment: And, btw, it's nice to accept answers if they helped.